# Pasing objects as component property in React JSX

Tags: reactjs

A React newbie's experiment:

```
React.renderComponent(
  <MyComponent item={name: "A Name", description: "---"} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Console error:

```
JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text
```

Doesn't seem to work like that. I have digged React documentation for a while but no dice yet.

Comment: What is `renderComponent(` supposed to be? A function call? A function definition? Where is `MyComponent` defined and how? The problem doesn't seem to be React but basic JS syntax. The snippet alone is incomplete and invalid, so it's no wonder that it doesn't work. I'm sure that the React documentation shows more than that.

Comment: Ah, so it's supposed to be a function call. You still have a syntax error. The last line should be `);`, not `};`. And you are not passing the value of `item` correctly. `foo={...}` denotes an expression in JSX, i.e. the prop value should be evaluated as JavaScript. You are then missing the `{...}` for the object literal. It should be `item={{name: "A Name", description: "---"}}`. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#attribute-expressions

Comment: Thank you. Thought double braces conflicts ...

Comment: Nope, you can use any valid JS expression inside the `{...}`. `name: "A Name", description: "---"` on it's own would not be a valid expression though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are not passing the value of `item` correctly. `foo={...}` denotes an expression in JSX, i.e. the prop value should be evaluated as JavaScript. You are then missing the `{...}` for the object literal. It should be

```
<MyComponent item={{name: "A Name", description: "---"}} />
//                 ^---       object literal       ---^
//                ^-----        expression        -----^
```

Alternatively, if you don't find that syntax very readable, you can assign the object to a variable first:

```
var item = {name: "A Name", description: "---"};
// ...
<MyComponent item={item} />
```

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#attribute-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you want inside `MyComponent` to access `this.props.name` and `this.props.description` instead of `this.props.item.name` and `this.props.item.description`, you can use this syntax:

```
var item = {name: "A Name", description: "---"};
<MyComponent {...item} />
```